# Calculate $ \sup_{ x\in X-\{0\}} \frac{d(x,E)}{\|x\|}$ , where $E \subseteq X$ is closed, proper subspace.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed $\mathbb K$-linear space and let $E \subseteq X$ be a closed, proper subspace. Calculate$$ \sup_{ x\in X-\{0\}} \frac{d(x,E)}{\|x\|}.$$

How can I calculate it? Please  give some hints.

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: since $E$ is  a subspace, $d(x,E)\le\|x\|$. This allows you to find an upper bound. To show that this upper bound is tight, you may apply Riesz's lemma.

Comment: By Riesz's lemma , for each $n \in \mathbb N$ and for $r= {n \over (n+1)}$ we get $x_r$ with $||x_r||=1$ s.t. $r \leq d(x_r, E)$. From here we just have to take $n \to \infty$ ? Am I right for the other inequality?